# Responsive DIV and background

Tags: html, css

For the first time i'm doing some responsive DIV'S and now i have made my responsive background and i wanted to my content look like this:

[image]

But it looks like this:

[image]

If someone could help me it would be great.. Here is my code that you see what i was doing

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XmqNy/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftColumn"><img src="projekt.png" width="400" height="400"></div>
    <div class="rightColumn"><img src="projekt2.png" width="400" height="400"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {width:100%;}

.leftColumn  {width:50%; float:left;}
.rightColumn {width:50%; float:left;}

@media(max-width:400px)
{
.leftColumn  { width:100px; float:none; display:block; position:relative; background-color:red; }

.rightColumn { width:100px; float:none; display:block; position:relative; background-color:blue; }

}
```

Images are 400 x 400 pixels and background image is 1920 x 1080

Comment: For future reference, don't use code tagging around URLs. They're links, not code. When tagged as code, we can't click on them. Additionally, you need to include code in your post if you are going to link a JSFiddle. Show us the code you've tried already.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you need based on your fiddle... is it suppose to be right when more than 400px and your problem is when less than 400px? is this what you want?http://jsfiddle.net/XmqNy/233/

Comment: Yes and it needs to be on center of the screen not in the left or center top it must be in center of the screen..

Comment: like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XmqNy/236/ ?

Comment: it's still the same this is how it looks now http://i.stack.imgur.com/xfG7pl.png and this is how i want it to look http://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ7tgl.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For background, use [background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) property (CSS3).

```
.container {width:100%;}

.leftColumn  {width:50%; float:left;}
.rightColumn {width:50%; float:left;}

@media(max-width:400px)
{
    .container {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background: url(http://www.extremedialer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/bg-1.jpg);
        background-size: 400px;
    }    
    .leftColumn  { width:100px; float:none; display:block; position:relative; background-color:red; }
    .rightColumn { width:100px; float:none; display:block; position:relative; background-color:blue; }
}
@media (min-width:401px) and (max-width:800px)
{
    .container {
        width: 800px;
        height: 800px;
        background: url(http://www.extremedialer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/bg-1.jpg);
        background-size: 800px;
    }    
    .leftColumn  { width:200px; height:200px; float:left; margin: 20px; display:block; position:relative; background-color:red; }
    .rightColumn { width:200px; height:200px; float:left; margin: 20px; display:block; position:relative; background-color:blue; }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XmqNy/235/

Comment: yes, but now i want that 2 divs center Verticaly, you know how to do that?

Comment: this is what it looks now  i.stack.imgur.com/xfG7pl.png and this is how i want it to look i.stack.imgur.com/jJ7tgl.png

Comment: oh yes, position the center of the screen, sory.
look: http://jsfiddle.net/7uDe8/1/

Comment: The container need position fixed, top 50%, left 50%. The margin left is less half width and margin top is less halt height. left column and right column need float left.

Answer (score 0):

try it in your css file:

```
@media(max-width:400px)
{
    .leftColumn  { width:100px;   position:relative; background-color:red; }

    .rightColumn { width:100px;   position:relative; background-color:blue; }

}
```

You don't need to write display:none.